# Receive the HTTP status after a request with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-headers

i'm sending data to a server and i want to receive the HTTP response status in order to check this status and provide the appropriate view

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String Login(@ModelAttribute("Attribute") Login login, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) {

          // Prepare acceptable media type
          ArrayList<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
          acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

          // Prepare header
          HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);

          HttpEntity<Login> entity = new HttpEntity<Login>(login, headers);

          // Send the request as POST
          try {
           ResponseEntity<Login> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://www.../user/login/", 
                   HttpMethod.POST, entity, Login.class);
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
      //here i want to check the received status
      if(status=="OK"){
         return "login"
      }
      else          
      return "redirect:/home";
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ResponseEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) object contains the HTTP status code.

```
// Prepare acceptable media type
ArrayList<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

// Prepare header
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);

HttpEntity<Login> entity = new HttpEntity<Login>(login, headers);
// Create status variable outside of try-catch block
HttpStatus statusCode = null;

// Send the request as POST
try {
  ResponseEntity<Login> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://www.../user/login/", 
  HttpMethod.POST, entity, Login.class);
  // Retrieve status code from ResponseEntity
  statusCode = result.getStatusCode();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
// Check if status code is OK
if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
  return "login"
}
else          
  return "redirect:/home";
```

Comment: I think that there is a little problem in the above code.When i'm trying it i see the statusCode to be always null. I'm looking at the server and i see that the request has been done. Do you have idea why?

Comment: @AlexDowining Typo (I had typed entity.getStatusCode instead of result.getStatusCode). Try with the edited version and see if that works better.

Comment: I'm trying this but i'm taking an exception at the  ResponseEntity<Login> result = restTemplate.exchange("http://www.../user/login/", 
  HttpMethod.POST, entity, Login.class); and i cannot execute the line: statusCode = result.getStatusCode();

Comment: @AlexDowining I added an initialization of the statusCode variable to null. If an exception is thrown the variable will remain null (or you could manually set a specific status code in the catch block.

Comment: Hi man and thank you for the responses. Actually my problem is that i take an exception and thus the statusCode=result.getStatusCode(); can not be executed.If you want you can take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507650/httpmessagenotreadableexception-spring-mvc

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with:

```
HttpStatus status = result.getStatusCode();
if(status == HttpStatus.OK)
```

See: [`ResponseEntity`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) JavaDoc.

BTW you should not compare strings using `==` operator like here:

```
status=="OK"
```

Instead use the following idiom:

```
"OK".equals(status)
```

Also method names in Java tend to start with lower case.