# how to write RestTemplate.put() in groovy using Spock

Tags: groovy, integration-testing, spock

I am writing integration test cases using spock in groovy. We are using restTemplate to call the operation for example like this

```
when:
String url="http://localhost:$port/user/password"
ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<User>> entity=restTemplate.postForEntity(url,changePasswordDTO,ResponseWrapper.class)

then:
    entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
    entity!=null
```

I have written integration test for POST and GET, but now when I am writing it for PUT, I am getting null pointer exception on **entity object**

I have written this for PUT, I know put operation will be null, But I am not getting any other way for this, Can someone please help me

```
String url="http://localhost:$port/applicant/{id}/status?blacklistingFlag&reason"
    map.put("id", "23")
    map.put("blacklistingFlag","0")
    map.put("reason","no reason")
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, null, null, map)
    ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<User>> entity=restTemplate.put(url,ResponseWrapper.class , map)

    then:
    entity.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK
    entity!=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but couldn't leave it without answer.
`restTemplate.put` is a `void` method so you won't be able to get a callback from it.

You should use `restTemplate.exchange` as you will get a `ResponseEntity` object in return.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473067/receive-the-http-status-after-a-request-with-spring-mvc).