# How to get the HTTP status of an API in spring boot when we hit it internally using Rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpresponse, spring-restcontroller

I want to get the object as well as the `HTTP response` of one `api` into another in `Spring` code. For that I am using a `rest template` and I am getting the desired `Object` from it successfully.

But I want to fetch `HTTP response` also for the respective `api`.
What should I do to get this?

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
System.out.println("quote "+quote);
System.out.println(quote.getType());
log.info(quote.toString());
```

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473067/receive-the-http-status-after-a-request-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 4):

`getForObject` method of RestTemplate only gets the result. If you're interest in the status code you should invode `exchange` which returns a `ResponseEntity` which has a `getStatusCode` method.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<Quote> response= restTemplate.exchange ("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", HttpMethod.GET, null, Quote.class);
    Quote quote = response..getBody();
    System.out.println("status "+response..getStatusCode());
    System.out.println("quote "+quote);
    System.out.println(quote.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks alot it just fulfill the requirement i was looking for