# How we can pass the response if ResponseEntity got failed(400 Error)

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, rest

I am hitting one API using RestTemplate exchange method, Here I am getting responseEntity of ClientResponse Type. If we have any Bad request in first line of code, I'll get 400 and cursor will go to the catch and throwing Error. So remaining code(For setting a response Data) is not executing .Instead of this I want to set the response Data and I want to set status code also and want to execute remain code. How we can do it, Do we need to use Flag variable ??

```
ResponseEntity<ClientResponse> responseEntity = this.getRestTemplate().exchange(API_URL,
                HttpMethod.POST, entity, ClientResponse.class);
                
        response.setResponseEntity(responseEntity);
        response.setValue(inputRequest.getValue));            
        response.setEndTime(LocalDateTime.now());
        response.setRequestPayload(gson.toJson(inputRequest));            
        response.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        response.setRequestHeaders(entity.getHeaders().toSingleValueMap());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("error occurred in service" + e.getMessage());

    }
    return response;
```

Comment: You need to handle all the exceptions and collect them and at the end, you can process that and return it to the client. use Aspect and global exception handler for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use restTemplate error handler for that. You can parse the error response returned from the rest template like 404 or some other error.

You can use those status code and error response to rest the response as per your need.

For that you need to define a class by implementing ResponseErrorHander.

```
public class ServiceResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters;

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        
        return (response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError() ||
                response.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        HttpMessageConverterExtractor<ServiceErrorResponse> errorMessageExtractor = 
                new HttpMessageConverterExtractor(ServiceErrorResponse.class, messageConverters);
        
        ServiceErrorResponse errorObject = errorMessageExtractor.extractData(response);
        
       throw new ResponseEntityErrorException(
               ResponseEntity.status(response.getRawStatusCode())
                                .headers(response.getHeaders())
                                .body(errorObject)
               );
        
    }

    public void setMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        this.messageConverters = messageConverters;
    }
}
```

And use it in your rest template bean like this.

```
RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new 
RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler();
//pass the messageConverters to errror handler and let it convert json to object
        errorHandler.setMessageConverters(restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);
```

Comment: look complicated, Simply I want to get the response from responseEntity and set the value later return response. Here My code is moving to catch id any error is coming in entity. I want to handle this error and set the status code and other data later return the response.

Comment: similar kind of issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473067/receive-the-http-status-after-a-request-with-spring-mvc

Comment: That will not work as resttemple will throw client exception. Either ou can get the response code from the exception or use handler.